# Copying values to an object clone/prototype

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following object where I want to initialize it with values (outside a class):

```js
let person = {
    firstName: undefined,
    lastName: undefined,
    get fullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}
let p = Object.create(person);
p.firstName = 'Ralph';
p.lastName = 'Smedley';
console.log(p.fullName);
```

Why doesn't the above work when doing the following?

```js
let person = {
    firstName: undefined,
    lastName: undefined,
    get fullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}
                         // use default Object so don't override inherited object
let ralph = Object.assign({}, person, {firstName: 'Ralph', lastName: 'Smedley'});
console.log(ralph.fullName);
```

What would be the proper way to do this second approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Object.assign`, the getters are invoked at that time (and the result is put as a data property onto the new object). Your getter isn't running after `ralph` is created - it's running before that.

```js
let person = {
    firstName: undefined,
    lastName: undefined,
    get fullName() {
        console.log('getting fullName');
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}
let ralph = Object.assign({}, person, {firstName: 'Ralph', lastName: 'Smedley'});
```

After that occurs, you're left with an object of:

```
{
  firstName: "Ralph"
  fullName: "undefined undefined"
  lastName: "Smedley"
}
```

So logging `ralph.fullName` will give you what exists in that property, which is `"undefined undefined"`

Using `Object.create`, on the other hand, does not invoke getters that may exist on the object - all it does is set the internal prototype.

If you wanted to copy over the method too, you could do:

```js
const person = {
    firstName: undefined,
    lastName: undefined,
    get fullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
};

const objectAssignWithGettersSetters = (target, ...args) => {
  for (const arg of args) {
    Object.defineProperties(target, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(arg));
  }
  return target;
}
const ralph = objectAssignWithGettersSetters({}, person, {firstName: 'Ralph', lastName: 'Smedley'});
console.log(ralph.fullName);
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. And then what would happen if I had a setter on the object? <-- seems just from testing it ignores it if there is a getter with the same name, and if there isn't a getter of the same name it sets it to `undefined`.

Comment: If there's a setter without a getter, it'll result in a property with the value `undefined` on the target object. If there's a setter and a getter, the getter will be invoked, resulting in a data property on the target object, and the setter will be lost in the transition.